# Give IIS on one server read access to folder on another server

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, iis-7

As [Mark Mitchell says it](https://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/)

> Microsoft IIS Server 7.0 and up offers a lot of new features in regards to application security. One of the new features is the ability to assign each of your ASP.NET applications their own isolated Application Pool.

I want to give one of these AppPools (living in server A) read access on another server (Server B) on the same domain.

Trying to do this, I have navigated to server B, but I cannot choose the AppPool users from Server A.

Is there any way to do this? If it is in fact impossible, is it then possible to make my website on Server A use an AD user instead of the AppPool user, so that I can assign read-access to this AD-user on the folder on server B?

I'm running IIS 7 on a Windows 2008 Server R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working around with this, the solution I ended up with was creating a custom AppPool, and then using an AD-user for this AppPool.

First, I added the AppPool

[image: Create new AppPool]

Then I navigated to the advanced settings, and set a custom account for this AppPool

[image: Use custom account]
[image: Specify AD-user]

Last I navigated to the advanced settings for the website, and set the Identity to the newly created "MyCustomPool"

[image: Select new AppPool]

With all this done, I was then able to set up permissions for the AD-user that I previously chose as the "Custom account" for the AppPool "MyCustomPool"